# When I mouse over a day, I want to call tooltip

Tags: fullcalendar

if I write like below, I can get into function but, don't know how to 
call tooltip event.
when I apply it to eventMouseover, it work perfectly, but with below, dosen't call anything.

```
 $('body').on('mouseover', 'td.fc-day, td.fc-day-number', function() {
           var start=$(this).data('date');
           var tooltip = '<div class="tooltipevent" style="width:200px;height:50px;background:#fff;position:absolute;z-index:10001; padding:20px; border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);">' + "SSSS" + '</div>';

           $(this).append(tooltip);
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Bootstrap tooltip plugin http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips . And then inside eventRender callback write following:

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
    $(element).tooltip({title: event.title});
}
```

This will work

[image]

**Update :** 
the above was for hover on an event,
this is for hover on day:

```
$(".fc-day").hover(function(){
   // code for creating tooltip
});
```

Comment: Thank you for answer! but its the one for mouse over on event. not a day. if I mouse over to a day with above my code, it get day. and as soon as it get day, I want to get tooltip

Comment: you can use the same code for day also. Just create a tooltip by the method described above in my answer.

Comment: I just modified my answer, check it